# Pythagorean theorem in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

This question is in the same spirit as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176723/what-does-the-pythagorean-theorem-really-prove/).

On one hand it is often stated,that the Pythagorean theorem means that Euclidean distance arises from a scalar product. But on the other hand most elementary proofs rely on surface arguments.

Is there a way to make the connection explicit using linear algebra terms ? In other words, is there a version of the Pythagorean theorem of the form "if a norm satisfies this condition regarding determinants, then it is given by a scalar product ?"

Another way of looking at the question is this. $\mathbb{R}^2$ with euclidean norm, determinant, and scalar product, is a model for the Euclidean plane. This somehow means that linear algebra can give us some insight about geometry.
Conversely, if the Euclidean plane is a model for a two-dimensional real space with determinants and norm, why must the norm be the one given by a scalar product ? What insight does Euclidean geometry give us about scalar products ?

One could argue that for the Pythagorean theorem angles are as important as surfaces, and that having angles implies a scalar product. But it seems to me the naïve conception of angles is very different from the abstract version of orthogonality in a scalar product space that we are used to.

Comment: What do you mean by “surface arguments”? And which connection do you want made explicit?

Comment: Well, the Pythagorean Theorem at the very least talks about distances, lengths. What is the distance between two points in the plane? Do you have a definition that is couched in the language of linear algebra?

Comment: @Joppy Pythagoras' proof was a cut and paste argument, Euclid's was also about areas.

Comment: @Lubin a distance is a norm on a vector space. Hence I am asking: what characterises the euclidean norm ? There is a Jordan-Von Neumann-Frechet theorem that says that a norm is euclidean iff it satisfies the parallelogram identity.

Comment: So "surface" means area? And "scalar product" means inner product?

Comment: @David K Yes. I'm sorry, I didn't notice my wording was somewhat unusual.

Comment: You can have an inner product space on $\mathbb R^2$ in which the inner product is different from the usual one, and the norm is not based on the Pythagorean Theorem. I'm not sure about the premise of this question.